# Numpy 4d array to tf.data.dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm following this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix but I'm trying to make my own input pipelines. I have a 4d numpy array (Num samples, Height, Width, Channels) and I use `ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` to create my dataset. However, when I call `ds.take(1)` it doesn't have the a dimension for the batch size. I can fix this by inserting `tf.expand_dims()` where necessary but I feel like there should be a way to do this in the dataset.

Comment: Tensorflow provides a `.batch()` method which takes a number for the batch size.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Also, @RichardX, I wrote my answer before I noticed your comment, honestly! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
for image in ds.batch(1).take(1):
    assert image.shape[0] == 1
    # do something with the image
```